# Finding a function in a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\left [ (m+1)f(x)+\frac{\mathrm{d}(\xi(x) f(x))}{\mathrm{d}x} \right ]y^{m}+\left [ (n+1)g(x)+\frac{\mathrm{d}(\xi(x) g(x))}{\mathrm{d}x} \right ]y^{n}=0$$

Find $\xi(x)$

I tried to do the following:

$\frac{\left [ (m+1)f(x)+\frac{d(\xi(x) f(x))}{dx} \right ]}{\left [ (n+1)g(x)+\frac{d(\xi(x) g(x))}{dx} \right ]}=\frac{-y^{n}}{y^{m}}$

The right hand side depends on y only, and the left hand side depends on x only, so each side is equal to C

$\left [ (m+1)f(x)+\frac{d(\xi(x) f(x))}{dx} \right ]=C \left [ (n+1)g(x)+\frac{d(\xi(x) g(x))}{dx}
 \right ]$

$(m+1)f(x) - C(n+1)g(x)=\frac{d(\xi(x)(Cg(x)-f(x)))}{dx}$

$\frac{\int (m+1)f(x)- C(n+1)g(x)}{Cg(x)-f(x)} =\xi(x)$

but I feel that my approach is totally wrong

Comment: It looks totally fine to me.

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki if it is fine, then how y^m/y^n= C ??

Comment: It means that $y$ takes a certain constant value as its solution, since $y$ doesn't depend on $x$. This sometimes happen in differential equation.

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki OK what about the constant C ? can I pick any constant arbitrarily? can I choose it to be 0 for example?

Comment: You can leave $C$ as arbitrary but you cannot pick any particular value for that.

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki OK, If I have another differential equation like this one: dy/dx = f(x) y^m + g(x) y^n , can both equations be consistent?

Comment: It's totally up to whether $y$ depends on $x$ or not. Is $y=y(x)$?

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki all what I know is these two equations

Comment: The equation you just gave clearly contains $y$ which depends on $x$, so it's not easy to solve unlike the one which you initially asked about.